# How do I change the path of an image when linking it in a HTML template?

Tags: python, html, django

When a category is clicked on, the user should be shown all of the items that are in that category. However, when I click on a category, the image of the items are not shown because the image is search for in `CATEGORY/media/images/...` (`CATEGORY` is the name of the category) instead of just `/media/images/...` This may be due to the fact that the path of the web page starts with the category name itself, so when the images are searched from the path.

How do I change the path that the images are searched from?

urls.py:

```
path('<str:name>/', views.category, name='category')
# so this would end up as a /Electronics/ if the Electronics category was clicked on
# so I think that this is why the image are searched from the wrong path - it is searched from /Electronics/media/images/...
```

category.html:

```
<div class="listings-container">
     {% for i in listings %}
        <div class="listing">
            {% if i.photo_present != None %}
            <div class="img-container">
                {% if i.photo_url != None %}
                <div class="img-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'listing' i.pk i.name %}">
                        <img src=" {{ i.photo_url }} " alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="img-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'listing' i.pk i.name %}">
                        <img src=" media/{{ i.photo_upload }} " alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

views.py: (irrelevant but aids in understanding the HTML)

```
def category(request, name):
    category = Category.objects.get(name=name)
    listings = Listing.objects.all()
    list = []
    for i in listings:
        if i.category == category:
            list.append(i)
    return render(request, 'auctions/category-page.html', {
        'category': category,
        'listings': list
    })
```

index.html: (the image is shown on this page - here for comparison):

```
<div class="listings-container">
    {% for i in listings %}
        <div class="listing">
            {% if i.photo_present != None %}
            <div class="img-container">
                {% if i.photo_url != None %}
                <div class="img-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'listing' i.id i.name %}">
                        <img src=" {{ i.photo_url }} " alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="img-center">
                    <a href="{% url 'listing' i.id i.name %}">
                        <img src=" media/{{ i.photo_upload }} " alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}          
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: I think the issue is in photo_upload, photo_url, can you share the Listing model

Comment: Its not because it works on the `index.html` page. I am going to share that.

Answer (score 0):

at first:
I know nothing about your models, but you don't need too much if and for loop in listings:

```
listings = Listing.objects.filter(category=category, photo_present__isnull=False)
```

at second:
You works wrong with relative paths:

```
<img src="{{ i.photo_url }}" alt="">
```

You receive `src="site/category/path_to_image.ext"`
i can imagine, you want:

```
<img src="/{{MEDIA_URL }/{{ i.photo_url }}" alt="HERE SHOUD BE SOMETHING">
```

Read more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp